# C# Open Form in a new Thread or Task?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, visual-studio

How do i open a new form in C#, with the thread or task.

example:

```
public void openform()
{
    Form _form = new Form();
    _form.show()
}

Thread _thread = new Thread(openform);
_thread.start();
```

if i use a Thread it opens the form and close it again.

Comment: Why would you want to open a form on another thead? Isn't the UI thread you have not enough?

Comment: You do not want to create multiple UI threads.  That's going to cause you numerous problems.  You want to have a single UI thread.

Comment: Is it because the new form takes a long time to open?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by adding another UI thread?

Comment: i want to be able to open a form with a new thread because its scanning a website and if i can open multiple Ui thread i can scan more websites at the same time sry for bad english

Comment: @amc The solution is to not do your non-UI work in the UI thread, and instead do it in background threads, rather than creating a background thread to do your UI work while you have your UI thread do non-UI work.  As the name implies, the UI thread is for UI work, and background threads are for background work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *can* create another UI thread if you simply set the `ApartmentState` to `STA` and start another message loop:

```
Thread _thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    Application.Run(new Form());
});
_thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
_thread.Start();
```

Note that you wont't be able to display a control that you create on the main thread on this form though. That's why it is generally a bad idea to create more than one UI thread.

Answer (score -1):

```
Thread thd = new Thread(() =>
            {

                //Do Some stuff 
                //Do some more stuff

                var dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
                dispatcher.UnhandledException += Dispatcher_UnhandledException; //you exception handling logic
                Dispatcher.Run();
            });
            thd.IsBackground = true;
            thd.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thd.Start();
```

based on your use case call `Dispacther.InvokeShutdown();` when done.

Answer (score -1):

By using `ShowDialog` it return only when the window is closed:

```
new Thread(() => new MyForm().ShowDialog()).Start();
```